# MS Access sub-form combobox disappears when linked to SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a MS Access frontend with both an Access and SQL Server 2019 backend. I am converting the Access backend to a SQL Server 2019. However, when I switch my source table `tblFiresCostEstimates` from Access to SQL Server, my subform no longer provides my combo box list.

Including an image of my form/subform connected to both data sources to provide visualization to my issue.

- The left screenshot: connected to MS Access linked backend table. My subform has my combo box functionality.
- The right screenshot: connected to SQL Server 2019 linked backend table. My subform no longer has my combo box functionality.

[image: Left Image – Connected to MS Access Linked Backend Table. My subform has my combo box functionality. Right Image – Connected to SQL Server 2019 Linked Backend Table. My subform no longer has my combo box functionality.]

Comment: There are not enough details to assist.

Comment: Not sure what more information you would like. Would you care to elaborate? The frontend works with an access table and does not with a SQL table as the data source.

Comment: Please add more details to this query.